# Do we get benefit to not take rice during the Gyaras day?

Tags: vishnu, fasting

During the Gyaras , it is said that we do not take rice because it prohibited during this day.
Why rice is prohibited on this day even who has not taken fast?
What should we do or do not do during the Gyaras day.

Comment: Your question is not exactly a duplicate of the marked question. Only half of it is duplicate. You can edit and vote for reopen. Highlight the two questions u have.like Question 1, question 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, i had to do a Google search to know what Gyaras (ekAdashi) actually is. :D

I am using [KAmakoti website](http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=55&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) as my reference here:

```
Why rice is prohibited on this day even who has not taken fast?
```

It is because on the ekAdashi day the pApa purusha ( the personification of all sins) takes shelter in the grains.

> yAni kAni cha pApAni brahmahatyAdikAni cha | annamAshritya tiShThanti
>   saMprApte harivAsare | aghaM sa kevalaM bhu~Nkte yo bhu~Nkte
>   harivAsare || [viShNupurANe]
>
> **Greatest of sins like brahmahatyA are present in anna or food on the
>   eleventh day of every pakSha. One who eats on this day, ingests these
>   sins and attains great misery.**

Another reference from Vishnudharmottara PurAna (a minor PurAna) which condemns the act of eating on this day:

> ekAdashyAM hi bhu~njAno viShNulokAcchyuto bhavet ||
>   [viShNudharmottare]
>
> One who eats on the day of ekAdashI is forever banished from vaikuNTha
>   i.e. loses eligibility to attain viShNuloka.

**What not to do during (ekAdashi) fasting?**

> upAvR^itasya pApebhyo yastu vAso guNaiH saha | upavAsaH sa vij~neyaH
>   sarvabhogavivarjitaH ||
>
> upavAsa involves getting rid of pApa karma and pApa chintana and
>   embracing good qualities, at least during the period of the vrata, **and
>   renouncing all luxuries including the food.**

...........................

> gandhAla~NkAravastrANi puShpamAlAnulepanam |
>
> **Perfumes, jewelry, luxurious clothing, garlands, anointments,
>   collyrium, abhyanga, tAmbUla charvaNa, brushing the teeth, are all**
>   considered to be **varjya (to be avoided) during upavAsa**.
>
> The same is stated in harivamsha:
>
> a~njanaM rochanamchApi gandhAn sumanasastathA | puNyake chopavAse cha
>   nityameva vivarjayet ||
>
> gAtrAbhya`NgaM shirobhya~NgaM tAmbUlaM chAnulepanam | vratastho
>   varjayet sarvaM yacchAnyadbalarAgakR^it ||

Some further not-to-dos which are however the same for all fasting days:

> It is interesting to note that **brushing the teeth during upavAsa or
>   vrata is banned** by several other authorities as well. vAchaspati
>   mishra quotes the following pramANa:
>
> upavAse tathA shrAddhe na khAdeddantadhAvanam | dantAnAM
>   kAShThasaMyogo dahatyAsaptamaM kulam ||
>
> Alternate authorities offer reconciliation by suggesting that the ban
>   here is on danta kAShTha saMyoga and not really on cleaning the teeth!
>   Hence cleaning the teeth with leaves etc without the use of kAShTha is
>   considered acceptable. Now, it is up to an individual if one decides
>   to give up the tooth brush and stick to flossing on the day of
>   upavAsa!
>
> nR^itya, gIta etc are also considered as luxuries and banned during
>   upavAsa, unless it is a part of pUjA and offered to the Lord.
>
> **Sexual activity, gambling and sleeping during the day** are also
>   **prohibited during upavAsa**:
>
> upavAsaH praNashyeta divAsvApAkShamaithunaiH || [devalaH]
>
> **Specifically during ekAdashI, maithuna is strictly prohibited**. One who
>   engages in maithuna during ekAdashI puts seven generations of his in
>   hell:
>
> upavAse tathA yaunaM hanti saptakulAni vai ||

Comment: Nice answer. You can also answer here [Why eating rice is prohibited on Ekadashi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13854/why-eating-rice-is-prohibited-on-ekadashi). This question seems duplicate.

Comment: First please check for the duplicate and then write the answer. Prefer answering the original question rather than a duplicate.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Ok thanks, so now the same answer i have to post there too. :D

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani And BTW this is not exactly a duplicate. Because it asks an additional Q: "What should we do or do not do during the Gyaras day."

Comment: Thanks for answer. And yes, this question has an extra point. If edited, can be reopened.

Comment: No, you should not post the same answer or similar answer to original and duplicate questions. You have to remove one of them(mostly duplicate only) or flag for mod intervention and ask for merging questions if you think you have taken great effort in answering this question. See [What do I do with my answer if the questions gets closed as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98488/what-do-i-do-with-my-answer-if-the-questions-gets-closed-as-a-duplicate)

Comment: @SS Both the answers are considerably different. And that's because both the Qs are also somewhat different. Also what kind of languages you are using " You have to"  " You should" Are these ur orders or what?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani What should i edit to come out from duplication. Please do not be in harry to mark duplicate. Thanks

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha You can ask `What should we do or do not do during the Gyaras day.`

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani .It was also included in that question.Ok no problem with it..Enjoy :)

Comment: Did you see the post I linked? I linked meta post. They are rules by SE.Did I link my post? Why do you say my orders? These rules are made after consensus at Meta.SE.The post I included is written in 2011 before many sites are started. They are not choices. They are policies. We are bound by them. Generally,  users write answers to either master question or dupe question. They don't write to both the questions. You could have added relevant info into that answer. If it's not dupe, edit the Q, comment not a dupe and reopen. Don't just assume by yourself.  **Search for dupe before answering**.